# How to change timestamp of movie on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, photos.app, file-transfer, exif

When I recorded a movie with my iPhone, the date was not set correctly. So now the video shows up in the wrong order in the Photos app.

<strike>It seems the video date is inferred from the file created/modified timestamp.</strike> How do I edit the timestamps of the file stored on my phone?

I figured out how to modify the timestamps of the file on my PC, but I don't know how to put them back on my phone while retaining the edited timestamps.

- Windows explorer does not support copying files to the iPhone
- iFunBox will copy files to the iPhone, but updates the timestamps at the same time

**update:**

MOV files have EXIF data, too. I used [ExifTool](https://ExifTool.org/) to edit the tags like this:

```
exiftool.exe IMG_2439.MOV \
             -"CreateDate"="2016:10:12 20:59:55" \
             -"ModifyDate"="2016:10:12 21:02:37" \
        -"TrackCreateDate"="2016:10:12 20:59:55" \
        -"TrackModifyDate"="2016:10:12 21:02:37" \
        -"MediaCreateDate"="2016:10:12 20:59:55" \
        -"MediaModifyDate"="2016:10:12 21:02:37" \
           -"CreationDate"="2016:10:12 20:59:55-05:00"
```

However, deleting/modifying this file on my phone must have removed it from the Photos app database... I can't see this movie at from my iPhone, now. Only from the file system when connected to a computer.

Answer (score 1):

**Modify the database at `/Photodata/photos.sqlite`.** (Camera roll photos are sorted by `zaddeddate`, so setting this date to `zdatecreated` will sort them in the expected order.)

More info and detailed steps:

- [Fixing the iPhone’s photo library](http://george-graphics.co.uk/blog/2010/08/14/fixing-the-iphones-photo-library/)
- [[Tutorial] Fix: iPhone Photo Database corrupt and/or Cameral Roll out of order](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3v2zjs/tutorial_fix_iphone_photo_database_corrupt_andor/)
- [Fix Corrupt Photo Database](https://insanelyi.com/topic/2211-fix-corrupt-photo-database/)